# Как правильно писать статические методы

Tags: javascript

Понимаю что я делаю не правильно, но не могу понять что именно. У меня есть класс покупателей, затем я создаю массив покупателей. Далее мне нужно вывести список покупателей в алфавитном порядке ,я это сделал с помощью статического метода. Потом мне нужно вывести покупателей у которых номер кредитной карточки находится в заданном диапазоне. Думаю я не совсем понимаю как работают статические методы в этом случае, сначала я хотел написать вот такой статический метод

```js
static rangeCreditCardNumber(minNumber,maxNumber){
  let arrRange = [];
   if (this.numberOfCreditCard >= minNumber && this.numberOfCreditCard <= maxNumber){
           arrRange.push(this.numberOfCreditCard);
   }
   return arrRange;
}
```

Но rangeCreditCardNumber не функция. Вообщем я запутался и не совсем понимаю как это можно сделать. Может нужно создать статические свойства с минимальным и максимальным значением, а затем возвращать массив клиентов у которых this.numberOfCreditcard входит в этот диапазон

```js
class Customer{
 constructor(name, surname, middleName, address, numberOfCreditCard, numberOfBankAccount){
   this.name = name;
   this.surname = surname;
   this.middleName = middleName;
   this.address = address;
   this.numberOfCreditCard = numberOfCreditCard;
   this.numberOfBankAccount = numberOfBankAccount;
 }


 showCustomerInformation(){
   alert(` Клиент ${this.surname} ${this.name} ${this.middleName}`);
   alert(`Адресс клиента ${this.address}, номер кредитной карты ${this.numberOfCreditCard} и номер банковского счёта ${this.numberOfBankAccount}`);
 }

static compare(a,b){
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1; 
 if (a.name == b.name) return 0; 
 if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
}

static rangeCreditCardNumber(minNumber,maxNumber){
 let arrRange = [];
  if (this.numberOfCreditCard >= minNumber && this.numberOfCreditCard <= maxNumber){
          arrRange.push(this.numberOfCreditCard);
  }
  return arrRange;
}

 set Name(nameOfClient){
     this.name = nameOfClient;
 }

 set Surname(surnameOfClient){
   this.surname = surnameOfClient;
 }

 set mmiddleName(middleNameOfClient){
   this.middleName = middleNameOfClient;
 }

 set Address(addressOfClient){
   this.address = addressOfClient;
 }

 set creditCard(creditCardNumber){

   this.numberOfCreditCard = creditCardNumber;
 }

 set bankAccount(bankAccountNumber){
   this.numberOfBankAccount =bankAccountNumber;
 }

 get Name(){
   return this.name;
 }

 get Surname(){
   return this.surname;
 }

 get Address(){
   return this.address;
 }

 get creditCard(){
   return this.numberOfCreditCard;
 }

 get bankAccount(){
   return this.numberOfBankAccount;
 }

}

let customers = [
 new Customer('Вртём','Гришин','Александрович','Витебск', 10, 1),
 new Customer('Аима','Д','Петров','Минск', 15, 1357900000),
 new Customer('Бртём','Иванов','Петров','Москва', 1, 96564)
];
customers.sort(Customer.compare);
alert(customers[0].name);
alert(customers[1].name);
alert(customers[2].name);
alert(customers.rangeCreditCardNumber(1,10));
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/static-properties-methods

Comment: а почему ты решил что нужны именно статические методы, а не обычные?

Comment: почему в случае статического метода `compare`, ты обращаешься к нему как  `Customer.compare`, а точно такой же статический метод `rangeCreditCardNumber` пытаешься вызвать у массива?

Comment: Не правильно понял. Я подумал что в методе compare мы просто сортируем массив , а в методе rangeCreditNumber мне нужно получить определённое количество клиентом из массива которые имеют нужные номера кредитных карта из диапазона

Comment: обрати внимание что в методе compare ты НЕ сортируешь массив

Comment: Ну да,  сортирует его метод sort, в compare мы только указываем как он это будет делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите инкапсулировать поля *Customer*, то следует убрать геттеры. Иначе этот код не имеет смысла: проще использовать объект без класса. Я бы предложил такую реализацию...

```
class Customer {
    _name = "";
    _surname = "";
    _middleName = "";
    _address = "";
    _numberOfCreditCard = "";
    _numberOfBankAccount = "";
    compare(b) {
        if (this._name == b._name) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this._name > b._name) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this._name < b._name) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            debugger;
        }
    }
    toObject() {
        return {
            name: this._name,
            surname: this._surname,
            middleName: this._middleName,
            address: this._address,
            numberOfCreditCard: this._numberOfCreditCard,
            numberOfBankAccount: this._numberOfBankAccount,
        }
    }
    static fromObject({name, surname, middleName, address, numberOfCreditCard, numberOfBankAccount}) {
        const customer = new Customer();
        customer._name = name;
        customer._surname = surname;
        customer._middleName = middleName;
        customer._address = address;
        customer._numberOfCreditCard = numberOfCreditCard;
        customer._numberOfBankAccount = numberOfBankAccount;
        return customer;
    }
}

const customers = [
  Customer.fromObject({name: 'Вртём', surname: 'Гришин', middleName: 'Александрович', address: 'Витебск', numberOfCreditCard: 10, numberOfBankAccount: 1}),
  Customer.fromObject({name: 'Аима', surname: 'Д', middleName: 'Петров', address: 'Минск', numberOfCreditCard: 15, numberOfBankAccount: 1357900000}),
  Customer.fromObject({name: 'Бртём', surname: 'Иванов', middleName: 'Петров', address: 'Москва', numberOfCreditCard: 1, numberOfBankAccount: 96564}),
];
```

Далее, произвести сортировку можно строчно, не раздувая объем класса.

```
customers.sort((first, second) => first.compare(second)).map((customer) => customer.toObject().name) // ["Аима", "Бртём", "Вртём"]
```

Тоже самое с выборкой по номеру карты

```
customers.filter((customer) => ((v) => v >= 10 && v <= 15)(customer.toObject().numberOfCreditCard)).map((customer) => customer.toObject().name) // ["Вртём", "Аима"]
```

Статический метод, по сути, функция, принадлежащая классу исключительно визуально. Статический метод не получает доступ ко всем инстанциям класса, если обратное не организовано в конструкторе сохранением каждой инстанции в статический массив.

Лично я понял статичные методы в принудительно объектно ориентированном языке C#. Так же, для работы на языке JavaScript, вам жизненно необходимо изучить [операторы spread и rest](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-spread-rest), [деструктуризацию](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring) и больше практиковаться...

Кроме того, в ближайшее время JavaScript сообщество полностью перейдет на функциональную парадигму. Попробуйте изучить библиотеку шаблонов проектирования [RambdaJS](https://ramdajs.com/)